# Check if winforms field is empty

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm wonder is it possible to get information if any of txt input fields are empty?

Currently I have 10 input txt fields and  I'm wonder how this can be done if I have for example 50 inputs, surely there must be a better way than checking every field.

Thanks

Comment: VB ?  or C# ? .. do you mean textbox ?

Comment: [This cartoon](http://noisydecentgraphics.typepad.com/.shared/image.html?/photos/uncategorized/2008/03/11/yourproduct.jpg) is classic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ

```
bool hasEmptyTextBox = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(tb => tb.Text.Length == 0);
```

If you also want to make sure if there is no whitespaces, then you can use [tring.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method:

```
bool hasEmptyTextBox = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                               .Any(tb => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text));
```

As @okrumnow correctly stated, this will check only TextBoxes which are direct children of your form or user control. If you need to check textboxes on every level, then you should do it recursively:

```
public bool HasEmptyTextBox(Control control)
{
   if (Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(tb => tb.Text.Length == 0))
       return true;

   foreach(var child in Controls)
      if (HasEmptyTextBox(child))
          return true;

   return false;
}
```

BTW It's beeter to put some [validation](http://blog.scosby.com/post/2010/02/11/Validation-in-Windows-Forms.aspx) on your text boxes, then check them all manually.

Comment: If they're all placed inside the same container.

Answer (score 1):

```
FormName.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c => c.Text.Trim() == "")
```